# How to convert this Java code to Kotlin Code?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm learning spring boot and new to kotlin.
A error will be reported when this Java function convert to kotlin code.
How to rewrite this kotlin function?

https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/

```
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner run(RestTemplate restTemplate) throws Exception {
    return args -> {
        Quote quote = restTemplate.getForObject(
                "http://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random", Quote.class);
        log.info(quote.toString());
    };
}
```

After convert these code to kotlin by idea:

```
 @Bean
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun run(restTemplate: RestTemplate): CommandLineRunner {
    return { args ->
        val quote = restTemplate.getForObject(
                "http://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random", Quote::class.java)
        log.info(quote.toString())
    }
}
```

[image: Type mismatch]

Please tell me how to correct this code.

Comment: SAM conversion not used correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48265190/8073652

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function literal / lambda isn't quite correct. In order to make the compiler able to convert it into an actual implementation of the Java interface `CommandLineRunner`, use [SAM Conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions).

It then looks as follows:

```
fun run(restTemplate: RestTemplate): CommandLineRunner {
    return CommandLineRunner { args ->
        TODO("not implemented")
    }
}
```

Notice **`CommandLineRunner { args ->...}`**

Alternatively, without SAM Conversion, the `object` syntax is handy:

```
return object : CommandLineRunner {
    override fun run(vararg args: String?) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what answer I need！See also [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-write-cleaner-code-with-kotlin-sam-conversions--cms-29304) can learn more about SAM Conversions.Thanks your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example of kotlin basic of converting a standard java interface to kotlin

```
// java
interface CommandLineRunner {
    public void run(String... args);
}


// kotlin
fun foo(): CommandLineRunner {
    return object: CommandLineRunner {
        override fun run(args: Array<String>) {
            // TODO
        }
    }
}
```

if it is a functional interface, you can use [SAM conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions)

```
// java
@FunctionalInterface
interface CommandLineRunner {
    public void run(String... args);
}

// kotlin
fun foo(): CommandLineRunner {
    return CommandLineRunner { args ->

    }
}
```

Hope you can have a better understanding of the java to kotlin conversion.